# Parse server edit (put) a specific object with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

So I am trying to setup an Node app with Parse and now I am trying to edit (put) a Object. The example on the Parse page wasn't really helpful. So I tried something alone. The Result:

```
 app.put('/edit/user', function (req, res) {
  var user = new Parse.Query('person');
  user.equalTo('objectId', req.body.id);
  user.find().then(function (result) {
    if (req.body.username != null) {
      result.set('username', req.body.username);
    }
    if (req.body.lastname != null) {
      result.set('lastname', req.body.lastname);
    }
    if (req.body.firstname != null) {
      result.set('firstname', req.body.firstname);
    }
    result.save(null).then(function (edit) {
      res.send(edit);
    })
  })
})
```

Now what happen is:
It fiend the object and result is right too. But when some attribute (like lastname) isn't null it goes in the "if" statement and then hang up by the "result.set(" ")". It also send nothing back. So in postman the calls never gets back.

Is there a diffrent way I can do it or is there some syntax error in my code.

Thank you already!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply just like that if some value is there then it goes in if condition otherwise it goes out. And some other conditions as well

```
   app.put('/edit/user', function (req, res) {
      var user = new Parse.Query('person');
      user.equalTo('objectId', req.body.id);
      user.find().then(function (result) {
       if(req){
        if (req.body.username) {
          result.set('username', req.body.username);
        }
        if (req.body.lastname) {
          result.set('lastname', req.body.lastname);
        }
        if (req.body.firstname) {
          result.set('firstname', req.body.firstname);
        }
        result.save(null).then(function (edit) {
          res.send(edit);
        })
       }else{
       console.log('undefined');
       }
      })
    })
```

Comment: but my Problem is, if the is something in the request (like the lastname = example), the code doesn't go further and just stop at this point.

Comment: simple use res.json where you want to stop the program . its sends the output and stop the program.

Comment: no you don't get me (maybe i just can't explain it ^^). I don't want, that he code stop there (it stops by result.set()). Because when it stop the changes doesn't save.

Comment: if (req.body.username) {
          result.set('username', req.body.username);
        res.json({msg:"username succesfully set"});
        }
try this . i think i can't get what you want